# search objects in s3 bucket using the node module

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the list_objects method of the aws-sdk node module (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) to try and search objects from a s3 bucket.

I would like to be able to search by filename, and in my case, we have multiple files with same name inside the bucket with different folder(prefix).

Is there a way to list all of those objects

Comment: I also faced similar situation while implementing in Java. I was not able to find direct way, so i first grab the list, found the relevant file(s) and then `getObject(file)`.
Will keep eye on this question for better approach

Comment: I tried adding Delimiter: '/' in the listObjects request and I got the list of folders as CommonPrefixes in the response. I am making the assumption that the file exists in the root directory as well as each of the folders. Easier than iterating through the complete list IMO

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `Delimeter` and `Prefix` params.

The following article should address your issue

https://realguess.net/2014/05/24/amazon-s3-delimiter-and-prefix/